# What camera has the highest number of frames per second?

Tags: video, high-speed

This is not meant to have any opinions; simply number-to-number comparison.

Comment: Available to consumers only? Or are you interested in academic, governmental, or other?

Comment: Are you asking about video frame rate or the frame rate of still cameras?

Comment: JoanneC: Video frame rate (i.e. the "trillion-frame-per-second" camera is irrelevant).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that will change rapidly over time and the accepted answer today will be incorrect next year or the year after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Vision Research Phantom](http://www.visionresearch.com/Products/High-Speed-Cameras/) cameras are very fast. The Flex can shoot 2,800 fps at full HD (1920x1080). At lower resolutions, the v711 can shoot at 1.4 *million* fps!

Answer (score 3):

The Nikon V1 does 320x120 at 1200fps.

The Optronis CamRecord CV does 1280x1024 at 100,000fps, or so I believe from http://www.optronis.com/produkte/high-speed-kameras-cv/camrecord-cv.html

Comment: seriously? :o - never could imagine!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using your definition of camera more loosely than the usual P&S and SLR methods of capturing pictures then [this is the fastest camera in the world](http://digitaljournal.com/article/316313), capturing a path of light 'as it moves', "equivalent to roughly 1 trillion frames per second".

Comment: That camera seems fast :)

Comment: no downvote, but that camera doesn't actually have a trillion frames per second. It is more like stop-motion animation. The researchers are being dishonest in describing their work.

Comment: @whatisname, it does have a rather impressive effective shutter speed however

Comment: Hence the loose definitions of camera ;) It's very impressive, but less so once you read the exact details of how it works

Answer (score 1):

Among off-the-shelf still cameras I think the DSLR record is 14 fps for [Canon EOS-1D X](http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/Digital_SLR/EOS_1Dx/index.aspx?specs=1) with locked mirror, AF and exposure.

Among mirrorless cameras the [Nikon V1 (search for 'buffer')](http://www.sansmirror.com/cameras/a-note-about-camera-reviews/nikon-1-camera-reviews/nikon-v1-review.html) can do 60 fps with locked AF, program exposure mode and auto ISO.

These figures are for burst mode, you can only take a few pictures at that speed. Typically 10-100 frame bursts, which fills up the buffer in 1-10 seconds.

Comment: I think the question was about video, though.

Answer (score 0):

In the world of the everyday DSLR the almost SLR APSC Sony A77 does 12 frames/second at 24 megapixel. This uses a fixed Pelucid mirror (largely transparent) so it not a true SLR as the term is usually understood.

Comment: Would the anonymous down voter like to explain why this answer does not add enough to the general body of knowledge that it is not worth just leaving alone but actually merits her considered downvote?